# Incorrect result set of timezone field in Teradata

Tags: timezone, teradata

I am trying to fetch the result of a table with timezone datatype field in TD 14 SQL assistant.

lock row for access sel * from uk_istl_rtm_data.rtim_message_event_history
where substr(message_name,1,5) in ('G1874','G1906','G1571')
and response_dttm   BETWEEN       '2021-03-30 00:00:00' AND   '2021-03-30 23:59:59'

This query is fetching records from  29th March 23:00 after daylight savings.

I have checked the TimeDateWZControl  of DBScontrol and its 3.

I am looking for  a way in which I can handle this timezone issue data at query level only.

Comment: What is the session time zone? (HELP SESSION). Maybe specify the intended (numeric) time zone offset as part of the constant.

Comment: timestamps with timezones make my head hurt. But unless I'm confused, when comparing a local timestamp to a timestamp with timezone, Teradata implicitly casts all the timezones to match.

Comment: If you do an EXPLAIN you will see that the literal (with no time zone) implicitly has the session time zone applied. (And comparisons are effectively based on the corresponding GMT / UTC values.)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the suggestion. I casted it  as below and it worked.

SET TIME Zone 'europe central';

SELECT
CAST(response_dttm  AS TIMESTAMP(6) FORMAT 'Y4-MM-DDBHH:MI:SSBZ') AT 'europe central'
from uk_istl_rtm_data.rtim_message_event_histor
where response_dttm  BETWEEN   '2021-03-30 00:00:00' AND  '2021-03-30 23:59:59';